# how to hide rows from datagrid which doestn get data from datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows

i have datagrid with 5 columns in it.
and i write some data to that datagrid, and i dont use any datatable.
now i want to hide some rows(like filtering)
how can i do this???

Comment: please be more specified about your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the index of the row you need to hide you can use the following statement:

```
dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Visible = false;
```